# Disable a user from cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

It is possible to deactivate the account with only the token or user identifiers without the need to use the admin functions "AdminDisableUser"?

Comment: Why do you not wish to use `AdminDisableUser`?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a way to disable a user without developer credentials. [This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html) is the list of API operations available for Cognito User Pools, but searching for "disable" results in only [`AdminDisableUser`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminDisableUser.html).

There is also [this issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/469) on Github where someone asked how to delete or disable a user. A [solution](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/469#issuecomment-392029145) was provided to demonstrate how a user can delete themself, but the provided [solution](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/469#issuecomment-619762754) for disabling a user was to use [Admin Actions](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/auth/admin). Admin Actions doesn't seem to allow you to limit a user to only disable themself though.

It looks like you'll have to set up a custom Lambda function or backend API to enable users to disable themselves.